# Display Ancestry name instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ancestry

My applications currently uses the Ancestry gem to create a navigation tree.

How do I display the name of a page which is the parent of another in the index view?

i.e. currently I do...

```
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to page.name, edit_page_path(page) %></td>
    <td><%= page.ancestry %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I want the page.ancestry to be the parent's name, not the ID.

Comment: Did you even read ancestry's README...? https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#navigating-your-tree

Comment: Yes, please look at my response bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><%= page.parent.name %></td>
```

isn't it working?

Comment: Unfortunately not, `I get undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: In that case your page does not have a parent. Did you set it somewhere?

Comment: This made complete sense; it worked after doing this: `<td><%= if page.ancestry then page.parent.name end %></td>`

Comment: Sorry, where are my manors... thank you both Miotsu and @Arjan